# Why my variable "c" has changed?

Tags: javascript, date, variables, object, var

```
var c = new Date(2015, 11, 25);
var d = c;
d.setFullYear(2000);
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
```

//Why my variable "c" has changed in this code?

Answer (score 2):

Line 1: You create a date object and assign a reference to it to `c`.

Line 2: You copy the value of `c` (a reference to a date object) to `d`

Line 3: You modify the date object. It is still referenced by two variables.

If you want to create a new date object and assign it to `d` then you need to do so explicitly.

```js
var c = new Date(2015, 11, 25);
var d = new Date(c);
d.setFullYear(2000);
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Huh, in all these years it's never occurred to me to just pass the whole date instance when making a copy :)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `c` did not change. What changed was the object that `c` refers to, which is that Date instance. After assigning the value of `c` to `d`, then *both* variables refer to the same Date instance. Two variables, one object.

You can make a copy of a Date instance like this:

```
var c = new Date(2015, 11, 25);
var d = new Date(+c);
```

or to be more explicit

```
var d = new Date(c.getTime());
```

Comment: does it applies only to the date () methods?

Comment: @DragomirMandic the same thing goes for any object that can be changed. It's the general way that objects and object references work in JavaScript.